# Can AWS rekognition analyze faces (emotion, etc.) in a video stream?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kinesis, amazon-rekognition

I thought that I could by at of today from the docs it looks like I can't (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/streaming-video.html). Seems like for video stream only face detection is supported, not analysis. Analysis says it only works for stored media (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/faces.html). Can someone confirm this?

If so, wonder what's a good way to "hack" video stream analysis on AWS? does it make sense to use a lambda function to read video from kineses, chop it into chunks, write to S3, and then let a face analyzer (rekognition) periodically poll S3 to analyze the faces? we kinda really need the sentiment analysis for video stream...

many thanks!!

Comment: how did you end up approaching this?

Answer (score 1):

You can send individual frames to rekognition, if you're painting bounding boxes with text on faces, you can update their position and the sentiment every n frames, depending on how many fps you need.

OpenCv is a good option for this although I don't know if you can use it in a lambda function. I guess you probably don't need the analysis done on every frame of the video.

Answer (score 0):

[*I haven't validated this approach, but please take a look and see if it might work for you*]

Rekognition Video allows you to detect and recognize faces in streaming video. The results are available in a Kinesis data stream. You can use that stream to identify and locate frames with faces. Then you can retrieve those frames as images and send them to Rekognition Image for further analysis, such as labelling of emotion.